# ASP.Net AJAX Call c# functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Been looking around for the last few days trying to figure out what the best route is. I am fairly new to ASP.Net so I am in need of a little assistance.

I like the idea of using Master Pages as it will make making changes to the template a lot easier! But I am running into some problems. I will just list them below and see where we can go, maybe this will help some other newbies like myself.

---

Dynamic Menu:
I am trying to create a menu system that will show certain links depending on the users role. This is simple enough until I just want the link to perform some functions and thats it. So I dont want it to postback or anything. So my next step was to try to use jQuery as I would with my php development. Problem is I cant seem to get my jQUery to call the master page code behind function. I've gone through all the tutorials I could find with WebMethods but just keep getting an error to the like of This type of page is not served.

General Classes:
In PHP sometimes I would have the need to just have some General classes that pertained to a specific area of the application. I would just use these to hold all the function I may need to call from jQuery. Is there something like that in ASP.Net? I tried just adding a class but again couldn't call it from jQuery. Is this something Web Services would be good at? I am still trying to understand their full use. Seems like we could use Web Services as a buffer between the client and the back end classes.

I look forward to any pointers or tips!

Comment: Instead of using ASP.NET webforms, as someone with PHP background, I suggest looking at ASP.NET/MVC - it would be a more natural fit.

Comment: I started down that road but I felt maybe I should learn windows forms and everything that goes along with it to get a better handle on ASP.Net. For smaller websites, just the normal mom and pop type sites I probably wouldn't use MVC I wouldn't imagine? If that's not correct maybe I should go down that route and just stick to it.

Comment: If you want to learn modern web development and care about web standards on the Microsoft platform, start with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Sounds like you were doing things backwards... Learning winforms in order to understand webforms? Webforms is a leaky abstraction with many issues that you would simply not have using MVC.

Comment: Sorry yes meant web forms! Ok maybe that's what ill do then, I did some research on whether or not to use Web Forms or MVC and basically everyone just said use whats best. But that doesn't help someone new know what to learn.

Comment: Going to mark this as completed but wanted to put this link up there for anyone else in the same situation as me.  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oded and jrummell made it very clear I should probably start with ASP.NET MVC first. It will most likely be an easier road for me moving from php.